# $3^n$ does not divide $4^n+5$ for $n\geq 2$

Tags: arithmetic, divisibility, exponentiation, p-adic-number-theory

Question as in the title : does anyone know how to prove that $3^n$ does not divide $4^n+5$ for $n\geq 2$ or find a counterexample ?

My thoughts : (1) I have checked that this is true for $n\leq 1000$.

(2) I asked a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3626676/3n-does-not-divide-8n1-for-n-geq-4) recently, and it was successfully solved with a method that uses a "lifting exponent lemma" which ultimately reduces to the identity $x^k-y^k=(x-y)(x^{k-1}+x^{k-2}y+\ldots+y^{k-1})$. Since $4^n+5$ cannot be so factored, this does not seem to apply here.

(3) For $r\geq 0$, denote by $q_r$ the smallest positive integer such that $4^{q_r}+5$ is divisible by $3^r$. It is easy to see that the order of $4$ modulo $3^r$ is exactly $3^{r-1}$, and hence $3^r$ divides $4^n+5$ iff $n\equiv q_r \ \pmod{3^{r-1}}$. It follows that $q_{r+1}\equiv q_r \ \pmod{3^{r-1}}$ and so we have a decomposition in base three, $q_r=\sum_{j=0}^{r-1}\varepsilon_j 3^j$ (where $\varepsilon_0=q_0$ and $\varepsilon_k=\frac{q_k-q_{k-1}}{3^{k-1}}\in\lbrace 0,1,2\rbrace$ for $k\geq 1$). The first terms of the $\varepsilon$ sequence are

$$
\varepsilon_0=1,\varepsilon_1=2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2
$$
No pattern seems to emerge at this point.

Comment: How did you get that decomposition ?

Comment: From my partial answer, the sequence of possible solutions $n$ are $$1,2,\ge5,\ge86,\ge3^{85},\ge3^{3^{85}-1},\cdots.$$ This shows how sparse the solutions are if any further ones exist, and thus it would be infeasible to simply check each integer using software.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire When you say "solutions if any", please clarify : do you agree that your partial answer starts from the assumption that there is at least one solution and show that another solution if any must be very large ; your partial answer finds nothing if there is a unique solution

Comment: You are correct. If there is a unique solution then $c\ne0$ and nothing (as far as I'm aware) can be inferred from that equality.

Comment: As for that sequence of $\varepsilon$'s, do I understand correctly that a unique solution $n \ge 2$ would mean that sequence becomes $0$ after finitely many terms? Whereas if we can show that the sequence does not eventually become $0$, there's no solution in $\mathbb N$? But then how would the existence of more than one solution translate to that sequence? Would it be periodic? I must misunderstand something because this is contradictory.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg The next record value of $n\equiv q_r$ needed for next larger $3$-adic evaluation $k$, increases by $1\cdot3^r$ or $2\cdot3^r$ every time $\varepsilon_r\ne 0$. The only way for $k$ to become larger than $n$ (and hence give us a counter-example), is if we get a subsequence of $q_r$ many consecutive zeroes $\varepsilon_{r+1}=0,\dots,\varepsilon_{r+q_r}=0$ after some $\varepsilon_r\ne 0$. The $q_r$ grows exponentially ($q_r$ is $c_k$ in my table), so the odds of such insanely large consecutive subsequence of $0$'s seems very unlikely. But "very unlikely" is not a proof, yet.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg And say we do get a counter-example $m\equiv q_{r+q_r}$ at that point. Then, $\varepsilon_m \ne 0$ again, and the record $n$ increases by $3^m$ or $2\cdot3^m$ again. Hence, the next counter-example must be $\ge 3^{m-1}$. Assuming these alternations of exponentially longer subsequences of consecutive $0$'s and breaks $\ne 0$ repeat, this gives the "sequence of possible solutions" that TheSimpliFire gave in their comment.

Comment: Thanks to @Merosity 's answer, I computed the 3-adic expansion of $\frac{\ln (-5)}{\ln(4)}$ for ~ $O(3^{t})$ to get first $t=10^5$ terms of the $(\varepsilon_r)$ sequence. From this, if a counter-example exists, it must be at least: (larger than $q_t$)
$$
n\gt 2\cdot 10^{47711}
$$
As we increase $t$, the counter-example can occur only if for some $t$:
$$
-t + \sum^{t-1}_{r=0} \varepsilon_r\cdot3^r \le 0
$$
Up to $t=10^5$ the longest streak of zeroes is $s\le 9$. To find a counter example above $t\gt 10^5$, we need that $s\le 9$ to turn into something $s\gg q_t=  2\cdot 10^{47711}$.

Answer (score 8):

This follows from an effective abc conjecture.
If $4^n+5=3^nm$ then the quality of this $(a,b,c)$-triple is
\begin{align*}
q(4^n,5,3^nm)&=\frac{\log(3^nm)}{\log(\mathrm{rad}(4^n\cdot5\cdot3^nm))}\geq\frac{\log(4^n+5)}{\log(30m)}=\frac{\log(4^n+5)}{\log(30)+\log(4^n+5)-\log(3^n)}
\end{align*}
which is larger than 2 for $n\geq9$, larger than 3 for $n\geq20$, and larger than 4 for $n\geq58$.
Conjecturally, there are no such $(a,b,c)$-triples.

---

Below is an unrelated attempt to figure out what's going on algebraic-number-theoretically.

---

In the ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, we have the factorization of ideals
$$(4^n+5)=(2^n+\sqrt{-5})(2^n-\sqrt{-5}).$$
Let $I=(2^n+\sqrt{-5})$ and let $I^\prime=(2^n-\sqrt{-5})$.
Note that $(2\sqrt{-5})\subseteq I+I^\prime$.
Then $I+I^\prime$ divides both $(2\sqrt{-5})$ and $(4^n+5)$.
However, $(2\sqrt{-5})$ has norm $20$ and $(4^n+5)$ has norm $(4^n+5)^2$ (which is coprime to $20$.
Thus, $I+I^\prime=1$ which shows that $I$ and $I^\prime$ are coprime.

Now suppose that $4^n+5$ is divisible by $3^n$.
We have the factorization of ideals
$$(3^n)=(3,1+\sqrt{-5})^n(3,1-\sqrt{-5})^n$$
where $\mathfrak p=(3,1+\sqrt{-5})$ and $\mathfrak q=(3,1-\sqrt{-5})$ are conjugate prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.
Since $I$ and $I^\prime$ are coprime, exactly one of the two possibilities holds:

- $\mathfrak p^n$ divides $I$ and $\mathfrak q^n$ divides $I^\prime$
- $\mathfrak q^n$ divides $I$ and $\mathfrak p^n$ divides $I^\prime$

The first case occurs when $n$ is even ($\mathfrak p$ contains both $2^n+\sqrt{-5}$ and $1+\sqrt{-5}$ so $\mathfrak p$ contains $2^n-1$ so $3\bigm|2^n-1$ so $n$ is even).
The second case occurs when $n$ is odd ($\mathfrak p$ contains both $2^n-\sqrt{-5}$ and $1-\sqrt{-5}$ so $\mathfrak p$ contains $2^n+1$ so $3\bigm|2^n+1$ so $n$ is odd).

Comment: To elaborate on the abc part: If you believe that qualities are bounded above by 4, then you need to manually check $n<58$, but if you believe the stronger statement that qualities are bounded above by 2, then you only need to manually check $n<9$.

Answer (score 6):

It's a little late here, but hopefully I can shed some light on why I think this is hard or impossible. Looking mod 9 for counterexamples, we can expand the binomial

$$f(n)=5+(1+3)^n = 5+\sum_{k\ge 0}3^k \binom{n}{k} \equiv 5+1+3n = 3(2+n) \mod 9$$

So the only cases we need to consider are when $n\equiv 1 \mod 3$, in other words $n \in 1+3\mathbb{Z}_3$, otherwise it's only divisible by 3 a single time.

First, all $|\cdot|$ in my post are the 3-adic absolute value. Let's reformulate the original question to be $|f(n)|\le 3^{-n}$ as the condition for there to be a counterexample. This suggests to me as $n$ gets larger, we are approaching a root o $f$, and since $f$ can be extended to be a continuous function of $\mathbb{Z}_3$, seen by its Mahler series above let's do that. We can directly solve for a root of $f(x)=4^x+5=0$, since both 4 and -5 are in the region of convergence of the logarithm power series,

$$r = \frac{\ln (-5)}{\ln(4)} \approx $$

```
1 + 2*3 + 2*3^2 + 3^3 + 3^4 + 2*3^7 + 3^8 + 3^12 + 3^13 + 2*3^14 + 3^17 + 2*3^18 + 2*3^19 + 3^20 + 2*3^22 + 2*3^23 + 3^24 + 3^26 + 2*3^28 + 2*3^29 + 3^31 + 3^32 + 3^36 + 2*3^38 + 3^39 + 3^40 + 2*3^41 + 2*3^42 + 3^44 + 2*3^45 + 2*3^46 + 2*3^48 + O(3^49)
```

This is the output from the [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) calculator for the input `log(-5+O(3^50))/log(4+O(3^50))` I arbitrarily picked about 50 digits of accuracy, but you can get many more without any trouble. The digits of this seems to match your $\varepsilon$ and $\gamma$ sequence mentioned in the question and an answer earlier exactly.

This root is also in $1+3\mathbb{Z}_3$ so it should be near other $n$ by continuity. Let's represent the difference $|r-n|=|h|$, and now write $|f(n)|$ a new way with this root $f(r)=0$.

$$|f(n)| = |f(r)-f(n)| = |4^r-4^n| =|4^n||4^h-1|= \left| \sum_{k\ge 1}3^k\binom{h}{k}\right|$$

$$|f(n)| = \left| 3h \sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{3^{k-1}}{k}\binom{h-1}{k-1}\right|=3^{-1}|h|$$

The series $\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{3^k}{k+1}\binom{h-1}{k}=\underline{1}+\frac{3}{2}\binom{h-1}{1}+\frac{3^2}{3}\binom{h-1}{2}+\cdots$ has 3-adic absolute value 1 because all binomial terms necessarily have $|\binom{h-1}{k}|\le 1$ and the exponent on $3$ makes all further terms after the first $1$ smaller than the rest, and by ultrametric inequality overtakes.

Now let's combine what we've gained with our reformulation 
$$|f(n)|= 3^{-1}|r-n| \le 3^{-n}$$

$$|r-n| \le 3^{-n+1}$$

What this says is for there to be a counterexample, $n$ must have all $n-1$ its first 3-adic digits in common with $\frac{\ln (-5)}{\ln(4)}$ in order to be a counterexample. But since $n$ is a natural number, we know its digits after its first $\lfloor \log_3(n)\rfloor$ digits are all $0$. This means in order for a counterexample to exist, there must be a very long string of $n-1-\lfloor \log_3(n)\rfloor$ consecutive $0$s somewhere in the digit expansion of $\frac{\ln (-5)}{\ln(4)}$. I think this is likely irrational and the problem is just as difficult as trying to find a string of repeating digits in say $\sqrt{2}$ in some sort of predictable way, so I doubt it's possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This is the most advanced answer so far.

Comment: Maximal repeating strings of $0$'s that can occur before the $m$*th* decimal place of some irrational number $x$ are tied to the irrationality measure of $x$. That is, such strings cannot be too long or they would result in impossibly good rational approximations of $x$. This was paraphrased from [second paragraph of this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/23551/88524) where they discuss normality and irrationality of $\pi$. For another example, I found [Let d be the decimal representation of sqrt(2). I am supposed to prove that a series of m consecutive zeroes...](https://bit.ly/2VHxHt3)

Comment: ^ That is, maybe it is still possible to find a good enough upper bound on something like ~ the irrationality measure of the $3$-adic representation of $\frac{\ln (-5)}{\ln(4)}$, or something in that context... that would then imply such a long string of $0$'s can never occur too early (otherwise we contradict the best possible rational approximations of the number in question), finally proving that a counter-example can't exist. *But this is just speculation from me*, I'm not able to say how hard this actually is.

Comment: Let $s_r$ be longest streak of $0$'s among first $r$ terms of $(\varepsilon_r)$, and let $f_r\sim q_r$ be the needed streak for a counter-example to occur beyond $r$ terms. Then we have (table of the record sizes of $s_r$):
$$\begin{array}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
r&s_r&f_r \\
\hline
7&2&1.10^{2}\\
12&3&1.10^{4}\\
194&5&8.10^{89}\\
746&8&1.10^{352}\\
5179&9&4.10^{2466}\\
\dots&\dots&\dots\\
\hline
\end{array}$$
The $s_r$ is much much smaller than $f_r$, as expected. We need to prove this holds for all $r$. The bound on $s_r$ should be deducible by above mentioned irrationality measure.

Comment: Interesting idea, I'll think about it to see if I can cook anything up.

Comment: There's a chance that with the existing literature this can be finished to show that there are only finitely many solutions $n$. Google for "linear forms in p-adic logarithms" (you want the p-adic analogue of Baker's theorem).

Comment: Whoops, I just saw your answer here. Sorry for the duplication.

Answer (score 2):

*(Not a full proof yet)* - *If a counter-example exists, it must be  $n\gt10^{10}$, so far.*

*Also, if $n_0$ is a counter-example, the next one is $\ge 3^{n_0-1}$, due to $\gamma_k$ sequence.*

---

TL;DR I'll try to formalize my observation [on your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3626800/318073) and apply it here. But unlike your previous question, here we cannot factor the expression nicely. Consequently, instead of a direct closed form, we get a "nontrivial" set of recurrences $a_k,b_k,c_k$ that determine $v_3$.

To prove that no counter-examples exist, we must prove an upper bound on $a_k$ or $c_k$.

---

We inductively sieve $3$ congruence classes at every step $k$:

$$n\equiv n^{(k)}_1,n^{(k)}_2,n^{(k)}_3 \pmod{3^k}$$

We have $v_3(4^n+5)=k$ for $n\equiv n^{(k)}_1,n^{(k)}_{2}$  and $v_3(x_n)\gt k$ for $n\equiv n^{(k)}_3$.

Denote $a_k, b_k, c_k=n^{(k)}_1,n^{(k)}_2,n^{(k)}_3$  and notice that WLOG $a_k\lt b_k$.

This gives that $v_3(4^n+5)=k$ for the first time when $n= a_{k}$, giving:

$$
k\lt a_k \implies v_3(4^n+5)\lt k
$$

We have $k=n$, and hence need to show that $k\lt a_k$ for all $k\gt k_0=2$.

In other words, we have that $v_3(4^n+5)$ is given by:

$$v_3(4^n+5)=
\begin{cases}
1, & n\equiv 0,2 \pmod{3^1}\\
\dots\\
k, & n\equiv a_k,b_k \pmod{3^k}\\
\dots
\end{cases}$$

If we start to sieve the congruences, we obtain the congruence classes:

$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc|ccc|ccc}
k &    &a_k&              &    &b_k&              &    &c_k&        \\\hline
1 & 0   &=&0+0\cdot3^0    & 2   &=&0+2\cdot3^0    & 1   &=&0+1\cdot3^0    \\
2 & 1   &=&c_1+0\cdot3^1  & 4   &=&c_1+1\cdot3^1  & 7   &=&c_1+2\cdot3^1  \\
3 & 7   &=&c_2+0\cdot3^2  & 16  &=&c_2+1\cdot3^2  & 25  &=&c_2+2\cdot3^2  \\
4 & 25  &=&c_3+0\cdot3^3  & 79  &=&c_3+2\cdot3^3  & 52  &=&c_3+1\cdot3^3  \\
5 & 52  &=&c_4+0\cdot3^4  & 214 &=&c_4+2\cdot3^4  & 133 &=&c_4+1\cdot3^4  \\
6 & 376 &=&c_5+1\cdot3^5  & 619 &=&c_5+2\cdot3^5  & 133 &=&c_5+0\cdot3^5  \\
7 & 862 &=&c_6+1\cdot3^6  & 1591&=&c_6+2\cdot3^6  & 133 &=&c_6+0\cdot3^6  \\
8 & 133 &=&c_7+0\cdot3^7  & 2320&=&c_7+1\cdot3^7  & 4507&=&c_7+2\cdot3^7  \\
9 & 4507&=&c_8+0\cdot3^8  & 17629&=&c_8+2\cdot3^8  & 11068&=&c_8+1\cdot3^8  \\
10 & 30751&=&c_{9}+1\cdot3^{9}  & 50434&=&c_{9}+2\cdot3^{9}  & 11068&=&c_9+0\cdot3^{9}  \\
11 & 70117&=&c_{10}+1\cdot3^{10}  & 129166&=&c_{10}+2\cdot3^{10}  & 11068&=&c_{10}+0\cdot3^{10}  \\
12 & 188215&=&c_{11}+1\cdot3^{11}  & 365362&=&c_{11}+2\cdot3^{11}  & 11068&=&c_{11}+0\cdot3^{11}  \\
13 & 11068&=&c_{12}+0\cdot3^{12}  & 1073950&=&c_{12}+2\cdot3^{12}  & 542509&=&c_{12}+1\cdot3^{12}  \\
14 & 542509&=&c_{13}+0\cdot3^{13}  & 3731155&=&c_{13}+2\cdot3^{13}  & 2136832&=&c_{13}+1\cdot3^{13}  \\
15 & 2136832&=&c_{14}+0\cdot3^{14}  & 6919801&=&c_{14}+1\cdot3^{14}  & 11702770&=&c_{14}+2\cdot3^{14}  \\
16 & 26051677&=&c_{15}+1\cdot3^{15}  & 40400584&=&c_{15}+2\cdot3^{15}  & 11702770&=&c_{15}+0\cdot3^{15}  \\
17 & 54749491&=&c_{16}+1\cdot3^{16}  & 97796212&=&c_{16}+2\cdot3^{16}  & 11702770&=&c_{16}+0\cdot3^{16}  \\
18 & 11702770&=&c_{17}+0\cdot3^{17}  & 269983096&=&c_{17}+2\cdot3^{17}  & 140842933&=&c_{17}+1\cdot3^{17}  \\
19 & 140842933&=&c_{18}+0\cdot3^{18}  & 528263422&=&c_{18}+1\cdot3^{18}  & 915683911&=&c_{18}+2\cdot3^{18}  \\
20 & 915683911&=&c_{19}+0\cdot3^{19}  & 2077945378&=&c_{19}+1\cdot3^{19}  & 3240206845&=&c_{19}+2\cdot3^{19}  \\
21 & 3240206845&=&c_{20}+0\cdot3^{20}  & 10213775647&=&c_{20}+2\cdot3^{20}  & 6726991246&=&c_{20}+1\cdot3^{20}  \\
\dots &&\dots&& &\dots&& &\dots&  
\end{array}$$

And so on...

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
 k &a_k=c_{k-1}+\alpha_k\cdot3^{k-1}  & b_k=c_{k-1}+\beta_k\cdot3^{k-1}  & c_k=c_{k-1}+\gamma_k\cdot3^{k-1}  \\
\end{array}$$

Where we do see that $a_k,b_k,c_k$ grow much faster than $k$.

To prove this fact, we need to observe the $\gamma_k\in\{0,1,2\}$ multipliers in the $c_k$ column, because that column determines the record values.

It appears that the runs of consecutive zeroes $\gamma_k=0$ are extremely sparse (much shorter) compared to the growth of $3^k$, hence there should be no solutions other than  $n=1$.

$$\gamma_k=1,2,2,1,1,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,1,1,2,0,0,1,2,2,1,\dots$$

But, at the moment, I'm not sure how to actually prove this observation for all $n$.

The first $21$ terms of $a_k,b_k,c_k$ in the table already give a large bound: If a counter-example exists, it must be at least $n\gt2\cdot 10^{10}$. (at least twice the size of the last $c_k$)

Comment: I've upvoted this answer for making things more explicit, but I would like to point out that the sequence of $\gamma_k$'s was already contained in the question as $\varepsilon_k$, and it seems there's no new insight into any patterns in that sequence.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg That is true. I merely present how I arrived to the sequence $\varepsilon_k = \gamma_k$, and tabulate the record values $n\equiv q_k=c_k$. Also notice that TheSimpliFire's observation on "the sequence of possible solutions" is justified by the zeroes of $\varepsilon_k = \gamma_k$ which delay the next record value of $n$ and allow for the $3$-adic valuation $k$ to increase a bit.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg  That is, every time $k$ increases a little bit (by $1,2$ or at most $3$ so far - observe the streaks of consecutive $0$'s of $\varepsilon_k = \gamma_k$ we have observed so far), the record value increases exponentially afterwards (after the streak of $0$'s get broken). But can we actually prove this, that these little bit's of $+1,+2,+3,\dots$ increments of $k$ caused by consecutive $0$'s will never catch up to the exponential growth of $+3^r,+3^{r+1},+3^{r+2},\dots$ of the record values $q_k=\gamma_k\equiv n$ caused by breaks of consecutive zeroes?

Answer (score 1):

*Partial answer:*

Suppose that for some natural $k>2$ that $3^k\mid4^k+5$; that is, there exists a positive integer $a$ such that $4^k+5=a\cdot3^k$. Notice that for a positive integer $s$, $$4^{k+s}+5=4^s(a\cdot3^k-5)+5=a\cdot3^k4^s-5(4^s-1).$$ Writing $4^{k+s}+5=b\cdot3^{k+s}+c$ for some positive integer $b$ and some integer $c<3^{k+1}$, it follows that $$c=3^k(a\cdot4^s-b\cdot3^s)-5(4^s-1).$$ Thus $3^k\mid4^k+5$ can have more than one solution only if $c=0$; that is, $$\frac{a\cdot4^s-b\cdot3^s}5=\frac{4^s-1}{3^k}$$ for all $s$. One criterion is that $5\mid b\cdot2^s-a$ as derived from the LHS.

This also explains the progressively sparse nature of solutions should more than one exist. LTE gives $$\nu_3(4^s-1)=1+\nu_3(s)\ge k,$$ so $\nu_3(s)\ge k-1$. If $k_0:=k$ is a solution then $k_1$, the solution nearest to $k$ must be of the form $k+r_1\cdot3^{k-2+t_1}$ with $r_1,t_1>0$. Iterating, the sequence of solutions $\{k_i\}_{i\in\Bbb N}$ satisfy the recurrence relation $$k_i=k_{i-1}+r_i\cdot3^{k_{i-1}-2+t_i}$$ with $r_i,t_i>0$ for all $i>0$. Of course, this grows incredibly fast.

Comment: Note that the known solutions $0,1,2$ satisfy the recurrence relation as $1=0+1\cdot3^{0-2+2}$ and $2=1+1\cdot3^{1-2+1}$.

Comment: (+1) I think I've observed an equivalent thing in my partial answer where i proceed to tabulate the recurrence(s) that determine $v_3(4^n+5)=k$ for $k=1,2,3,\dots$.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth. I like to check for patterns. For $n$ up to a million and and a half, I printed out only when the 3-adic valuation of $4^n + 5$ increased, i.e. set a new record.

---

```
n   n+2   v_3(4^n + 5)   log(n)
4  6 = 2 * 3    2  1.38629
7  9 = 3^2    3  1.94591
25  27 = 3^3    4  3.21888
52  54 = 2 * 3^3    5  3.95124
133  135 = 3^3 * 5    8  4.89035
4507  4509 = 3^3 * 167    9  8.41339
11068  11070 = 2 * 3^3 * 5 * 41    13  9.31181
542509  542511 = 3^3 * 71 * 283    14  13.204
2136832  2136834 = 2 * 3^3 * 7 * 5653    15  14.5748
n          n+2                  v_3(4^n + 5)   log(n)
```

============================

When a new record is set, the new exponent of $3$ is, roughly, comparable to $\log n$  and eventually much, much smaller than $n$ itself.

==========================

I have now started a run for $n$ up to 1,234,567,890. At some point it will become clear that merely storing the huge number is slowing the computer to uselessness and I will stop it.

Comment: The next record should be $n=2136832$. We can inductively find that the record values are given by $\{ c_k : c_k=c_{k-1}+\gamma_k\cdot3^{k-1}, c_1=1, \gamma_k\in\{0,1,2\} \}$ but I'm still trying to figure out how the $\gamma_k$ sequence behaves (the problem are consecutive $\gamma_k=0$).

Comment: @Vepir   very good.

Comment: We can compute all records below $10^{10}$ in less than a minute, using a congruence sieve. (see recurrence $c_k$ in my partial answer).

Comment: My attempt duplicates that of @Merosity, but the $9$-ary expansion of $\lambda=\frac{\log(-5)}{\log 4}$ is $\dots811818324016157;_9$, where as usual for $p$-adic numbers, you read from right to left (most significant at the right-hand end). By cutting off the expansion to an integer wherever you want, you get your numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, but please check it carefully. I guess it brings us no closer to a conclusive statement, and perhaps is just a rephrasing of every other answer.

You ask whether $3^n|(4^n+5)$ ever happens except when $n=1$. Thus you’re asking whether $v_3(4^n+5)=m\ge n$, and we want to show this is impossible.

Well, if it does happen, then $v_3\bigl(4^n-(-5)\bigr)=m$, i.e. $4^n=-5+3^mu$ with $u\in\Bbb Z_3^\times$.

Now I call in the assistance of the logarithm, $\ln(z)$, given by the series formula you know from Calculus, valid for $z\in1+3\Bbb Z_3$, which fortunately happens for both $4$ and $-5$, as well as, of course, $4^n$. From what you know about the logarithm, we see:
\begin{align}
\ln(4^n)=n\ln(4)&=\ln(-5)+3^mu'&(u'\in\Bbb Z_3^\times)\\
n&=\frac{\ln(-5)}{\ln(4)}+3^{m-1}u''&(u''=3u'/\ln(4)\in\Bbb Z_3^\times)\,,
\end{align}
because $v_3(\ln(4))=1$. We might as well call $\ln(-5)/\ln(4)=\lambda$.

But wait. This would be saying that $\lambda$ and $n$ agree in their first $m-1$ ternary digits. But $n$ doesn’t have that many digits, it has only roughly $\log_3(n)$ digits. All that remains to check is that $\lambda$ does not have
a huge run of zeros in its ternary expansion, which certainly seems more than
plausible, and is well beyond my capabilities.